# How to get a @Configuration object in ServletContextListener?

Tags: spring, servletcontextlistener

I am having here a `ApplicationConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration implements DatabaseConfiguration {    

    @Value("${jdbc.driver}")
    private String jdbcDriver;

    // ..

    @Override
    public String getJdbcDriver() {
        return this.jdbcDriver;
    }

    // ..
}
```

which provides certain kind of information about my application e.g. which JDBC driver I want to use. However, I don't know how I can use it as I am bootstrapping my server. How can I get hands on the initialized `ApplicationConfiguration` object and what is the best place to do this with Spring.

My current ansatz is using a `ServletContextListener` but at this point I don't know how to access the configuration object either:

```
public class BootstrappingServerConfig implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

        // ..

        // How can I load my application configuration at this point
        // or is there a better place to do that actually?
        ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration;

        try {
            SqlDatabaseBootstrapper.executeMigration(dataSource, applicationConfiguration);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }   
    // ..
}
```

What can I do here? Is it a good idea to use a `@Configuration` object like that in the `ServletContextListener` or would I do this kind of initialization somewhere else? If it's okay what I plan to do .. how can I get the configuration object?

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. Read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet and docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-container-config: Spring already provides a servlet context listener, and other programmatic ways of boostrapping the application.

Comment: @JBNizet If I'm getting this right then I should do this all in a `WebApplicationInitializer`? I ask because all sample code I find does actually some Servlet initialization routines.

Comment: @JBNizet It appears that I cannot autowire `WebApplicationInitializer` just like that - how do I access my configurations in `WebApplicationInitializer#onStartup`?

Comment: Use a AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer as documented to bootstrap your application. And if you need to do something when the application starts, don't try defining a ServletContextListener. Instead, do the job in one of the beans of your Spring application, for example in a method annotated with PostConstruct, or in a method observing the ContextStartedEvent Spring event.